What's the best way to obtain all text from all pages under every teamspace in Notion?
Currently, I'm manually doing this by going to each page within each teamspace, clicking the 3 dots in the top right, clicking Export, and then exporting as 'Markdown & CSV'. This is obviously very time consuming, as within each teamspace I'm in there's many pages, and to top it off I'm in many teamspaces.
I have an API key. Is there a programmatic way to get this data easily?
I explained this above.
